# How to handle special character in JSON

Tags: json

I have a column definition for the grid, i'm trying to put it in a JSON n load. There are few special characters and function for which I'm getting Invalid JSON Error

```
[ 
   { 
      "headerName":"",
      "field":"",
      "headerCheckboxSelection":true,
      "checkboxSelection":true,
      "width":45
   },
   { 
      "headerName":"A-1 PORT",
      "width":110,
      "cellRendererFramework":"params => {
          return this.renderCells(params)
        }",
      "field":"a1Port",
      "tooltipField":"A-1 PORT",
      "icons":"{
          sortAscending: `<img src=${ascArrow} style=\"margin-left:65px;color:black; position:absolute\" />`,
          sortDescending: `<img src=${dscArrow} style=\"margin-left:65px;color:black; position:absolute\" />`}"
   }
]
```

How to escape functions and special character in this case

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is with the line breaks in your `cellRendererFramework` and `icons` attributes, since JSON does not support literal line breaks. If you intend to keep those attributes as strings (rather than turning the `icons` attribute into another object), you could try the following:

```
[ 
   { 
      "headerName":"",
      "field":"",
      "headerCheckboxSelection":true,
      "checkboxSelection":true,
      "width":45
   },
   { 
      "headerName":"A-1 PORT",
      "width":110,
      "cellRendererFramework":"params => { return this.renderCells(params) }",
      "field":"a1Port",
      "tooltipField":"A-1 PORT",
      "icons":"{ sortAscending: `<img src=${ascArrow} style=\"margin-left:65px;color:black; position:absolute\" />`, sortDescending: `<img src=${dscArrow} style=\"margin-left:65px;color:black; position:absolute\" />`}"
   }
]
```

If you want to preserve the line breaks in your string, you can insert `\n` wherever you want a line break.